# How to prevent white space only from going to the database?

Tags: javascript

I have this JavaScript code that only allows users to enter letters and white space. If I allow that, the user can now enter the name as white space only and it will go to the database. Is there a way to prevent the user from entering white space only and force them to add letters?

And an optional question, can I prevent the user from entering two white spaces?

```
<script>
    function lettersOnly(input) {
        var regex = /[^a-z & " "]/gi;
        input.value = input.value.replace(regex, "");
    }    
</script>

<input id="fullname" placeholder="fullname" onkeyup="lettersOnly(this)">
```

Comment: If this is a real issue, you need to tackle the back-end part of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex, and it will allow for one whitespace only. Otherwise, it will be removed.

```
var regex = /\s\s+/gi;
input.value = input.value.replace(regex, "");
```

And if you need to remove all whitespaces, you can try

```
input.value.replace(/\s/g,'')
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just leave your code as is and when the user submits the form, you get rid of any whitespace. Something like:

```
string.replace(/\s/g,'')
```

The \s character matches ANY number of whitespaces, so that also solves your problem of preventing the user from entering two or more whitespaces.

However, if having whitespace in the name is a real problem, you should consider doing this on the back-end, to prevent the possibility of people bypassing your regex replace and inserting unwanted values into the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a following check condition before invoking service.

> input.trim() !=== ""

Comment: `.trim()` only gets rid of the first and last whitespace in a string.

Comment: Dragos, I'd think this method would work just fine, `.trim()` removes all leading and trailing whitespace, and it would ultimately result in an empty string `""` in the case that an entire string is whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to pretty easily prevent only whitespace, use `.charAt()` to check if the first character is whitespace.

if the entire string is whitespace, then your first character is definitely whitespace.

Example:

```
if (input.value.charAt(0) == " ") {
  //Do your things
}
```

As far as checking whether or not two immediately adjacent spaces are present, you can do that with regEx relatively easily, using an expression like `[ ]{2,}`.

In all seriousness, you're probably better off using a well-known, predefined form-validation library for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid only white spaces given as input

Just add the following check condition

```
If ( input.trim() == "" ){
    Expression
}
```